# How do you slow down a sample without losing so much quality?

Tags: effects, recommendations, sample

I've tried a few different time stretch tools and they all yield the exact same results of distortion and no high frequencies. How do you slow down samples without making them sound terrible?

Comment: Can you add which tools you've tried so far along with any relevant settings, should help getting a better answer.

Comment: Audacity, Edison, Waves

Comment: What do you mean by samples? Sample rate, or sampled recordings?

Comment: Either, sampled recordings require a fixed sample rate.

Answer (score 1):

[REAPER](http://www.reaper.fm) has multiple different time-stretch algorithms that can be used, each with their own sound and strengths. Try experimenting with those. Additionally, if you are losing high-frequency content, consider adding a harmonic exciter to the stretched sample to add more "shine" back to it

Answer (score 1):

Time stretch tools can't produce (or interpolate) frequencies that aren't there.  If you are planning to time stretch a signal, sample with 96kHz at least.  Assuming that your microphone and A/D converters play along, that should give you signal content (even if its quality degrades in the inaudible ranges) to somewhat above 30kHz.  When time-stretching, this gives some meaningful content to bring down into the audible range rather than the dead silence above the cutoff frequency that otherwise has to be there.

Comment: I've already recorded samples at 96kHz and I get the same problem.

Comment: Go higher - 192k.